# Postgres query without comma between column names

Tags: select, postgresql-9.3

If I run a query (without comma between the column names)

```
SELECT columnA columnB FROM someTable
```

Postges returns the first column. I expected an error..
What's the purpose of this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword `as` is optional for a column alias and therefor `columnB` is an alias for `columnA`.

Your statement is equivalent to:

```
SELECT columnA as columnB 
FROM someTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign column labels to the columns in your select list. For example:

```
SELECT columnA my_col FROM someTable;
```

Here `columnA` is the actual column in the table `someTable` and `my_col` is the label assigned to the `columnA`.

Your query was:

```
SELECT columnA columnB FROM someTable;
```

Here, although you expected PostgreSQL to throw an error, but this is a valid query for PostgreSQL. This is because PostgreSQL thinks of `columnA` as an actual column and `columnB` as a label assigned to the preceding column. This is the reason why it returns only the first column in the result i.e. `columnA`.